# how to add and get value from this child array using react

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIzX3.png)

```
[1:{
id: "3245fe9f-968b-4eb8-a575-3bcc41139766"
key: "9597a0d5-24f5-4dad-bfbc-807cda59617b"
measurement: "Length"
unit: [
0: {
unitName: 'Milimeter',
shortName: 'mm'
},
1: {
unitName: 'Meter',
shortName: 'm'
}
]}]
```

[enter image description here][2]

[enter image description here][2]

I want to get values for this component.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPUWB.png

Comment: can you provide more description, like how your full array looks like, or above is main array variable and you want to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful that if you give some description for it.

It seems like you are trying to access the inside data. For that you can use loops.
Here is example

```
arr.forEach(ele => {
     ele.unit.forEach(unitObj => {
         //here you can access the unitObj data. Either get or add
     })
})
```